# how to change new line and tab settings of a file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

editing files of a folder in vscode. the tabs are 4 and new line is something other than CRLF because when I copy and paste to notepad the code shows up as a single line.

but my user settings are tab-size: 2.  And open a 2nd instance of VSCODE. The tab settings are 2. And I can copy/paste to notepad with the lines showing correctly.

how to change the tab setting of a file.  And how to have new line after every line?

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of your `settings.json`?

Comment: {
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "workbench.sideBar.location": "left",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false
 }

here is an example.  had a usercontroller.js file in a folder.  It was tabbing 4 spaces.  I saved all the code. Deleted userController.js.   Then added it back. Pasted the code.  Now, VSCODE is tabbing normally - 2 space.

Comment: Also, in the bottom right of your editor, it should say what CR+LF standard is in use, and the space/tab rule. What does it say?

Comment: Have you restarted VS Code since you made the change?

Comment: says CRLF spaces 2.    But the files that are giving me grief say LF and spaces 4.

So I change to CRLF.  terrific.  But where does VSCODE get the "4 spaces" from?

Comment: By clicking on the LF and spaces 4 icons for the offending files, you can change it.